# NVIDIA GPU Activity shows application called "System"

Tags: gpu, nvidia

There is a program called "System" that is continuously running on my dedicated GPU inside my laptop.:

[image: GPU Activity]

What does this program do and how I can make sure it runs on the integrated graphics card, instead of the dedicated Nvidia card?

Comment: Been getting this on my asus laptop as well. Really annoying since it seems like it always keeps the gpu running. Currently it's showing 3 such "system" icons. It's weird that the icon next to it looks like the nvidia icon..

Comment: I am seeing , the same thing on my ACER Predator laptop too. No clue where its coming from.

Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I kinda found the answer that is working for me on my 3070 laptop. Turns out my WSL is using my Laptop nvidia gpu. I dont do anything in it thats GPU heavy , but still its using.

And the second WSL is started it captures GPU directly. So the way to solve is is by creating a file in your profile.
This can be done by

[image: typeing %userprofile% in run and hit enter]

After opening the user profile. open a file name  .wslconfig in the directory. If this does not exist simply create it.

at the end of the file simply add lines from below

```
[wsl2]
gpuSupport=false
```

this will stop WSL from taking GPU and bringing the laptop , or Desktop temp down.

If you want to use GPU in the wsl , AI modeling or some other reason remove the  gpu support line from wslconfig , or marking it true should also work i guess. I havent tried that one.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and so far it seems to work on my Lenovo Legion 7 Pro. Really annoying to find out what hogs the dgpu.